# laravel mix compiler not work on function javascript native

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

please help the teacher
about laravel mix with native javascript
every time I create a native javascript function to compile in resource / asset / app
the function is not running
after I browse the compile result all the javascript functions wrapped with webpack so it can not work
how to the solution
thank you

example I made
from

```js
    function publisher() {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // event.preventDefault();

        console.log('working');
    }
```

and the result after I compile so it can not work please solution

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  // The module cache
/******/  var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/  // The require function
/******/  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/   // Check if module is in cache
/******/   if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/   }
/******/   // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/   var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/    i: moduleId,
/******/    l: false,
/******/    exports: {}
/******/   };
/******/
/******/   // Execute the module function
/******/   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/   // Flag the module as loaded
/******/   module.l = true;
/******/
/******/   // Return the exports of the module
/******/   return module.exports;
/******/  }
/******/
/******/
/******/  // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/  __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/  // expose the module cache
/******/  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/  // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/  __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/   if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/     configurable: false,
/******/     enumerable: true,
/******/     get: getter
/******/    });
/******/   }
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/  __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/   var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/    function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/    function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/   __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/   return getter;
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/  __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/  // __webpack_public_path__
/******/  __webpack_require__.p = "/";
/******/
/******/  // Load entry module and return exports
/******/  return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 40);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ 40:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

module.exports = __webpack_require__(41);


/***/ }),

/***/ 41:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

function publisher() {
    console.log('working');
}

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

Comment: What command do you use to compile it? `npm run production` will compile it into native JavaScript.

Comment: npm run watch and npm run dev

Comment: Generally, the code above works in modern browsers. This is the output of development scripts. But for production you want to use `npm run production` which will compile it into a minified version ready for production.

Comment: still does not work if there is a solution to disable additional webpack scripts so that the results are written in the source file

Comment: Which part is not working? What's the output you expect?

Comment: just like this
and in gulp can also
I just follow laravel structures and this is a problem I found when in laravel if I use other plugins like gulp and parceljs
may be but the structure will be very messy   
 function publisher() {
        console.log('working');
    }

Comment: Please post your settings in `webpack.mix.js`